# 3.3V LDO identification similar but smaller than SOT-223

Tags: identification, ldo

I'd like to identify or find a replacement for a LDO component in the board above:

[image: LDO in question with a ruler next to it]

- It's a 3.3V LDO.
- It reads "AMS1117 3.3 DN18".
- The body is around 4mm width.
- Similar to SOT-223 package, but it's smaller.

I was looking for AMS1117 but according to datasheet it is available only in SOT-223, TO-252 and SO-8 factors.

He're another photo, with a SOT-223 AMS1117 that I had at hand. I was considering bending LDO but then I saw that top "tab" pin won't fit, so it doesn't look like a viable option.

[image: Top view]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-outline_transistor

Comment: a possible alternative https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/389/dm00236470-1798725.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *The body is around 4mm width.*

It could be a SOT-89 package like [this version](http://www.toponeic.com/uploadfiles/pdf/I2/AMS1117.pdf) of the AMS1117: -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A SOT89-3 package looks like a smaller version of a SOT-223.

The body will be around 4.5 mm in width, and the lead spacing is 1.5 mm or 3 mm between the centerlines of the outer leads.

Armed with an idea of the package, go to your favorite supplier and put that and your other needs into their selector.

Answer (score 0):

Some second-source vendors make the AMS1117 in other packages, such as [the 4.5mm SOT-89.](http://www.toponeic.com/uploadfiles/pdf/I2/AMS1117.pdf)